# Where Android Studio upgrade Kotlin compiler?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

On first installation of Android Studio and Kotlin compiler, `kotlinc` has been available on:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\bin
```

Now, I have upgraded Kotlin through Android Studio to last release 1.4. and it is already available:
[image]

Yet, typing `kotlinc -version` on console still returns: `Kotlin version 1.3.71`.

I can see that previously mentioned `kotinc` folder has not been updated.

Thus, where is the resulting Kotlin upgrade of Android Studio?